# I am getting error "expecting IDENT, found '('" while executing this query.

Tags: hibernate

Error is "(" after SET in my update query.  Please help me to resolve this.

```
String hql = "UPDATE table1 tb1 SET (tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3, tb1.col4) = (SELECT tb2.col1, tb2.col2, tb2.col3, tb2.col4 FROM table2 tb2 WHERE tb1.col5 = tb2.col5 AND tb2.col6 = :col6)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("col6", value);
int results = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: HQL is not SQL. If it was, it would be named SQL.

Comment: Perhaps you should try smth like `session.createNativeQuery`